# Web service call with a SHA-384 ECDSA certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, .net-4.8

For the project I am working on I have to convert the following legacy code to use a SHA-384 ECDSA certificate, .NET Framework 4.8 as target.

Is it possible natively in C# or do I need some help like BouncyCastle lib and how?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography; 
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

[...]

// Certificate is in PKCS#12 format and contains a private key, certificate is password protected with the session id
var certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Certificate.ToString());
var certificate = new X509Certificate2();
certificate.Import(certificateBytes, sessionId, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

var result = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( url );

result.Headers.Add( "x-jwt-authorization", $"Bearer {JSONWebToken}" );

result.ClientCertificates.Add( Certificate );

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I tried to find a solution/explanation online but didn't work (keep getting a "Not supported" for the PrivateKey property when trying to import the certificate, and a 403 Forbidden as server response).
Also if I want to keep backward compatibility, how do I distinguish if the Base64 string contains a X509 or a SHA one to support both?

Comment: It should work with Net 4.8.  SHA-384 is TLS 1.3.  Since Net 4.7.2 TLS is by default done by OS and not in Net.  What OS are you using?  Some older OS do not support the new encryption modes.  The certificate need to be loaded into stores for both machine and user.  Also make sure the csproj is not using Net for TLS.

Comment: @jdweng I am working wih Windows 10 as a client. What do you mean with "Also make sure the csproj is not using Net for TLS" ?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true#for-wcf-message-security-with-certificate-credentials

Comment: `cert.PrivateKey` does not work for ECDSA keys, which is part of why it's `[Obsolete]` in newer versions of .NET (the caller needs to use `cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey()` instead).  Other than that, it's unclear to me what you're looking for here.  To know what key algorithm the certificate is associated with, use `cert.PublicKey.Oid.Value`